# Access two structs with the same name (module)

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

I noticed that the Linux kernel has two structs with the same name (`module`). One is found in [`include/linux/module.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/module.h#L360) and the other one is found in [`scripts/mod/modpost.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/scripts/mod/modpost.h#L117). Now, I know that `THIS_MODULE` is assigned to the struct in `module.h`, but how can the kernel know which struct it should use?

`THIS_MODULE` is defined as a macro inside [`export.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/C/ident/THIS_MODULE)

```c
#ifdef MODULE
extern struct module __this_module;
#define THIS_MODULE (&__this_module)
#else
#define THIS_MODULE ((struct module *)0)
#endif
```

I would like someone to explain the code above

---

Another question I have is how can I access the module struct which is in `modpost.h`?

Answer (score 2):

Everything under `scripts/` is for **user-space utilities** used for building the kernel and its modules. Headers from this directory are **never included into the kernel module** code, so these definitions are never accessible to the modules.

When you search for some type/variable/function for use in the Linux kernel code, you could safely ignore everything which is found under `scripts/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It literally means if the macro MODULE is defined then you get the first definition for THIS_MODULE, otherwise you get the other (null pointer).  This happens at compile time.  It is the same for which struct to use, most likely by which header file is included.

You include modpost.h for the declaration, and to access variable you need your code to run in a process where this variable is alive.  From context, I would guess it is when you load your module with modprobe.

Comment: When I try to include `modpost.h` the compiler says that the file doesn't exists, even though it does in `/usr/src/$(uname -r)/scripts/mod/modpost.h`

Comment: Do you include that search path with `-I /usr/src/$(uname -r)/scripts/mod` when you compile your program?

Comment: What command accepts that argument (`-I`)?

Comment: Your compiler (gcc).

Comment: I don't use GCC to compile kernel modules... I use the Linux kernel make system.

Comment: https://qnaplus.com/how-to-compile-linux-kernel-module/ see INCLUDE_DIR.